# WordPress Toggle excerpt and content using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I found code on here that partially solved my problem for showing/hiding the main content and displaying an excerpt on a main WordPress page. When i click the read more button the excerpt suddenly disappears and the main content doesn't display.

JQuery isn't my strongest point so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 $(function () {
 $('.mainContent').hide();
 $('a.read').click(function () {
     $(this).parent('.excerpt').hide();
     $(this).closest('.tenant').find('.mainContent').slideDown('fast');
     return false;
 });
 $('a.read-less').click(function () {
     $(this).parent('.mainContent').slideUp('fast');
     $(this).closest('.tenant').find('.excerpt').show();
     return false;
 });
 });


<div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="" class="read">Read More</a>  </div>
 <div class="mainContent"><?php the_content(); ?><a href="" class="read-less">Read Less</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(function () {
     $('.mainContent').hide();
     $('a.read').click(function () {
         $(this).parent('.excerpt').slideUp('fast');
         $(this).closest('.tenant').find('.mainContent').slideDown('fast');
  //       $('.mainContent').show();
         return false;
     });
     $('a.read-less').click(function () {
         $(this).parent('.mainContent').slideUp('fast');
         $(this).closest('.tenant').find('.excerpt').slideDown('fast');
         return false;
     });
 });
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RcZeN/)**

Comment: Still had the same issue with that code so i just stipped the code down to basic .show .hide when the links are clicked and that made it work. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: @user2480082, did you see the demo? what effect were you looking after?

Comment: I seen the demo not sure why it wasn't working on my test site. I wasn't really looking for any effect that was just some code i came across online which would have done the trick. So the areas i removed weren't really needed.

Comment: @user2480082, do you get some error in the console on your site?

Answer (score -1):

You were missing .tenant

TRY THIS

```
<article class="tenant">
<div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="" class="read">Read More</a>  </div>
<div class="mainContent"><?php the_content(); ?><a href="" class="read-less">Read Less</a>    </div>
</article>
```